# How do I display the key and updated values together obtained from a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, key-pair

My code is supposed to remove synonymous words in the dictionary that are 7 or fewer characters long and I will need to display it in key order once I have done all the removing. However, I have no clue how to get the key and the updated values together. The intended output should be exactly like this:

(Sorted keys alphabetically):

```
dangerous : ['hazardous', 'perilous', 'uncertain'] 
show : ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose']
slow : ['leisurely', 'unhurried']
```

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
             'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack'],
             'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}

def main():
    edited_synonyms = remove_word(word_dict)
    key_order(edited_synonyms)

def remove_word(word_dict):
    dictionary = {}

    synonyms_list = word_dict.values()
    new_list = []
    for i in synonyms_list:
        new_list.extend(i)

    for word in new_list:
        letter_length = len(word)
        if letter_length <= 7:
            new_list.pop(new_list.index(word))

    value = new_list 
    keys_only = word_dict.keys()
    key = keys_only
    dictionary[key] = value
    return dictionary


def key_order(word_dict):
    word_list = list(word_dict.keys())
    word_list.sort()
    for letter in word_list:
        value = word_list[letter]
        print(letter, ": ", value)

main()
```

An error that has occurred so far is "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'"

Comment: `dict`s cannot be sorted. You should use an `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved with one-liner:

`waka_dict = {key: [w for w in word_dict[key] if len(w) > 7] for key in word_dict}`

It will return the needed dict:

```
{'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain'],
 'show': ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
 'slow': ['unhurried', 'leisurely']}
```

(It will save the original lists order)

---

If you want to be your dict ordered, you should keep in mind that Python dicts are non-ordered. You should use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#ordereddict-objects) for it:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(waka_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
             'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack'],
             'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}

result = {i:list(filter(lambda x: len(x)>7, word_dict[i])) for i in word_dict }

key_sorted =sorted(result.keys(), key=lambda x:x.lower())
# sorting alphabetically
solution = {i:result[i] for i in key_sorted}

print(solution)

output

{'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain'], 
 'show': ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
 'slow': ['unhurried', 'leisurely']
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    value = new_list 
    keys_only = word_dict.keys()
    key = keys_only
    dictionary[key] = value
```

This is the code that raises the error. `key` is not a single key, it's an object of type `dict_keys` (returned by `word.dict.keys()`). Such an object cannot be a single key because dictionaries use hashmaps and, like the error said, `dict_keys` is unhashable.

The easiest solution (keeping your code) would be putting your whole function in a loop iterating over the keys first so that at each iteration you deal with exactly one dictionary entry.